# PHP No Insertion in postgresql

Tags: php, forms, postgresql

this is my code that it's not working

```
$c=pg_connect ("dbname=pfe_abht user=postgres password=123456") 
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

if( isset($_POST['type']) || isset($_POST['id_demandeur']) 
    || isset($_POST['date'])
) {
    $type=$_POST['type'];
    $id_demandeur=$_POST['id_demandeur'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    $pg="INSERT INTO dossier (id_dossier,type,id_demandeur,date)".
        " VALUES ('',$type','$id_demandeur','$date')";
    $r=pg_query($c,$pg);
    var_dump($r);
    pg_close($c);
    echo'insertion enfiiiin !! ';
} else echo 'aucune insertion n est effectuee';
```

I get allways no insertion has done

Comment: Please add `create table dossier` statement

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your query:

```
" VALUES ('',$type','$id_demandeur','$date')"
            ^ here a '  is missing
```

Change it to:

```
" VALUES ('','$type','$id_demandeur','$date')"
```

You should always check for SQL errors with [`pg_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php) when you have problems with a query.

---

Another thing: Your `if` statement:

```
if( isset($_POST['type']) || isset($_POST['id_demandeur']) 
    || isset($_POST['date'])
)
```

will be true as soon as at least one variable is set. If you need all these variables in your query you should change the `||` to `&&`:

```
if( isset($_POST['type']) && isset($_POST['id_demandeur']) 
    && isset($_POST['date'])
)
```

or just check all at once:

```
if( isset($_POST['type'], $_POST['id_demandeur'], $_POST['date']) )
```

Comment: ohh, very cool, SYNTAX ERROR in Statement. not in php.. good catch.

Comment: thank you very much in addition of these errors I had a error in html thank you again